# Explicitly tell the code analysis tool that a method will return a inherited class instead of the base class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

My code follow a structure similar to this code segment:

```
class Message:
    """ base class """
    msg = "dummy message"

class SpecialMessage(Message):
    """ inherited class """
    msg = "Hello, World!"

def read_message(val) -> Message:
    if val > 1:
        return SpecialMessage()
    return None

def read_special_message() -> SpecialMessage:
    return read_message(2)
```

I'm currently using PyCharm.
The code works when I run it, but PyCharm still complains that read_message returns Message instead of SpecialMessage.
In C# you could solve it by doing:

```
public Message readMessage(int val)
{
    if (val > 1)
    {
         return SpecialMessage();
    }
    return null;
}

public SpecialMessage readSpecialMessage()
{
    return (SpecialMessage)readMessage(2);
}
```

Where Message is an abstract class.

Is there a similar thing we can do in Python to explicitly tell the code analysis tool that the read_message() method in this case should return SpecialMessage which is an inherited class of Message?

Or should I avoid this kind of implementation?

Edit:
The question regards the static analysis done in PyCharm, not the Python interpreter.

Comment: You don't have to tell the *interpreter* anything. Rather, you have to let the static analysis tool you are using know. The equivalent in Python would be to use `typing.cast`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think you should write up the latter part of your comment as an answer, showing how to use `typing.cast` in the OP's example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `typing.cast` as suggested by juanpa.arrivillaga we can do:

```
import typing

...

def read_special_message() -> SpecialMessage:
    return typing.cast(SpecialMessage, read_message(2))
```

The static type checking tool present in PyCharm will then accept the code.
This has no effect on the actual runtime environment and the code would in fact function the same without the type casting.